# MDP and a given policy and the correctness of the state-value function

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

Is the following statement correct?

"For an MDP and a given policy, the Bellman equation can be used to check the correctness of the state-value function."

Comment: What do you mean by ‘correctness’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it's correct.  Bellman equation is a set of linear equations rather than a single equation for the usual tabular cases. If we put these equations together, it would be clear how to calculate all the state values. See S&B book page 60:

> The value function $v_{\pi}$ is the unique solution to its Bellman equation.

$v$ is the state-value function and $\pi$ is a given policy as you specified.